# Machine Learning (NLP) on AWS. Cloud9? SageMaker? EC2-AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nlp, amazon-sagemaker, aws-cloud9

I have finally arrived in the cloud to put my NLP work to the next level, but I am a bit overwhelmed with all the possibilities I have. So I am coming to you for advice.

Currently I see three possibilities:

- **SageMaker**

  - Jupyter Notebooks are great
  - It's quick and simple
  - saves a lot of time spent on managing everything, you can very easily get the model into production
  - costs more
  - no version control
- **Cloud9**
- **EC2(-AMI)**

Well, that's where I am for now. I really like SageMaker, although I don't like the lack of version control (at least I haven't found anything for now).

Cloud9 seems just to be an IDE to an EC2 instance.. I haven't found any comparisons of Cloud9 vs SageMaker for Machine Learning. Maybe because Cloud9 is not advertised as an ML solution. But it seems to be an option.

What is your take on that question? What have I missed? What would you advise me to go for? What is your workflow and why?

Comment: The question is very unclear. Do you look for an easy work environment where you can quickly test your models or lokking for automated production like training and inference of existing algorithm?

Comment: I am looking for an easy work environment where I can quickly test my models, exactly. And it won't be only me working on it, it's a team effort.

Comment: version control - git is pre-installed on SageMaker notebook instances, as a command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for an easy work environment where I can quickly test my models, exactly. And it won't be only me working on it, it's a team effort.

Since you are working as a team I would recommend to use sagemaker with custom docker images. That way you have complete freedom over your algorithm. The docker images are stored in ecr. Here you can upload many versions of the same image and tag them to keep control of the different versions(which you build from a git repo).

Sagemaker also gives the execution role to inside the docker image. So you still have full access to other aws resources (if the execution role has the right permissions)

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb
In my opinion this is a good example to start because it shows how sagemaker is interacting with your image.

**Some notes on other solutions:**

The problem of every other solution you posted is you want to build and execute on the same machine. Sure you can do this but keep in mind, that gpu instances are expensive and therefore you might only switch to the cloud when the code is ready to run.

**Some other notes**

- Jupyter Notebooks in general are not made for collaborative programming. I think they want to change this with jupyter lab but this is still in development and sagemaker only use the notebook at the moment.
- EC2 is cheaper as sagemaker but you have  to do more work. Especially if you want to run your model as docker images. Also with sagemaker you can easily  build an endpoint for model inference which would be even more complex to realize with ec2.
- Cloud 9 I never used this service and but on first glance it seems good to develop on, but the question remains if you want to do this on a gpu machine. Because you're using ec2 as instance you have the same advantage/disadvantage.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I'd like to call out first is SageMaker notebook is not the only IDE environment in which you can interact with other components of SageMaker such as training and hosting. In fact you can make API calls to SageMaker training/hosting through Cloud9 or any IDEs you've installed on EC2 or even your laptop, as long as you have AWS SDK or SageMaker Python SDK installed.

Regarding the choice of the IDE, it's really up to your particular needs. SageMaker notebook is Jupyter based (now also supports JupyterLab beta), ML focused, and fully managed. Hundreds of Python packages that are commonly used in ML, as well as Tensorflow, Keras, MxNet, SageMaker Python SDK, etc., are preinstalled and automatically maintained for you. It also integrates more closely with other components of SageMaker as one can imagine.

Cloud9 is a managed IDE too but it is for general purpose rather than ML specific. If you want to use Jupyter on cloud9 it requires extra work from your side. It does not preinstall and maintain the version of common ML/DL related packages like SageMaker notebook does.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all questions follow the rules. Those questions that do not, such as this one (opinion-based and asking for recommendation without proper requirements), will be closed and possibly deleted. When they are, your answer will be deleted too.